# Associate player id to a transaction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

The way my app works is, I have users that have registered with me and they can log in and buy coins. The coins are in-app purchases using StoreKit.

The way I validate receipts is by sending them to my server. Along with the receipt, I send along the player's userid so my server knows who to credit.

Here is the problem. Lets say the transaction fails. When the app tries to do validation again, I will not know which user bought this.

Is there some way to add some metadata to a transaction so I can later know which user account bought it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a transaction failing? Are you talking about the communication between the app and the app store or between the app and your server after a successful buy from app store?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida I am talking about both. If my App never receives the transactionCompleted notification, it will only receive it once the app restarts and we no longer know who bought the item. Likewise, if my server does not respond we do not finishTransaction and on app restart we do not know who bought it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't add info to a SKTransaction.

What I usually do is a queue of unverified transactions. That queue usually has objects that have all the information needed by your server (your player id), the transaction itself, and its state (does the transaction has been completed, for instance?)

I try to dispatch that queue every time the app connects, and if it fails more than X times then I prompt a pop-up asking for the user to send an email with the details of the issue.

Comment: Where do you store this queue? Also, what happens in the event that the user accidentally deletes the queue (uninstall/reinstall)?

Comment: You can store that queue in the keychain, and it solves both of your problems (keychain is persistent between installations)